# Trying to reference a portable library with SlSvcUtil.exe

Tags: wcf, silverlight, portable-class-library, slsvcutil

Can someone confirm that the `/reference` switch does not work with `slsvcutil.exe` when I'm pointing it to a portable library? It seems, that it just ignores the types provided in a portable library and creates its own classes in reference.cs, which results in duplicated types in the silverlight project, which references the portable library.

Is there a reason, why it should not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826401), and the answer is correct! For some (unexpected) reason a default constructer solves the issue. It's even okay to make it privat. Weird.